# Approval process using Tasks and Sharepoint Custom list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, custom-list, approval

I have created a custom SharePoint list called "Issue Tracker" and enabled content approval in versioning settings. When I enabled that, it added approval columns automatically. I have created a workflow using SharePoint designer wherein whenever a user uploads a document by entering the Approver name, a task is assigned to the approver. When the task is approved, I am not able to set in SharePoint designer to change the status to Approved. Please find the below screenshots of my list and workflow.

#### Custom List

[image: Custom List]

#### SharePoint Designer Workflow

[image: SharePoint Designer Workflow]

Answer (score 0):

To update moderation status we can use SPD Workflow List Action `Set Content Approval status to Approved`.

You can refer below screenshot
[image]

Comment: Hi Bharat, I tried but it's not changing the approval status when the task outcome is approved. If I remove your red box, then it's triggering an email and the workflow status etc.

Comment: Did you publish workflow using full control user? If it's not trigger then there must me some issue to update Moderation status. could you please find exception and tried to resolve it.

Comment: Bharat, I am the administrator and so I have full access. What do you mean by moderation status? To explain clearly, I have enabled the "Require content approval for submitted items?" in versioning which added the Approval columns. The flow is able to trigger only till the creation of task.

Comment: moderation status is Approval status. Can you send error that occur after task completed?

Comment: Hi Bharat, there's no error but the workflow is working only until the creation of task. Can I contact you in skype or some other ways? Thanks

Comment: Bharat, I found something really strange. When I removed content approval in settings, the workflow is triggering and making it as approved. Is it possible for the document to appear only when it is approved using list? Currently all the items are visible to users irrespective of whether it is approved or not.

Comment: That why we used approval in settings to not display document to other user before approve document.

Comment: I have created same workflow as you see in image and it's work fine. Can tried to add red box statement on your workflow and approve task using workflow see what error occur.

Comment: Instead of the above, I would like to send an email whenever the approval status is Approved. How do I do that? What is the action on the sharepoint designer?